# Using methods to make a circumference calculator

Tags: c#, console, geometry

So i have made a small console calculator for working out the circumference of a circle. Yet i would like to rewrite it using methods. But i don't know where to start. Can anyone help me

```
using System;

class Circle
{
        static void Main()
    // Circumference of a circle: C=2πr
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the radius of your circle: ");
        double radius = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double pi = 3.1452;
        double area = 2 * pi * radius;
        Console.WriteLine("The Circumference of your circle is: "+ area);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll have to be more clear.  What would you like to rewrite using methods?  How will you group functionality?  There's very little here to extract.

Comment: using methods i want to groupe the maths part (radius, pi, area) and group the Console.WriteLine parts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;

class Circle
{
    public static double GetCircumference(double radius)
    {
        return 2 * Math.PI * radius;
    }

    static void Main()
    // Circumference of a circle: C=2πr
    {
        Console.WriteLine("What is the radius of your circle: ");
        Console.WriteLine("The Circumference of your circle is: " + GetCircumference(Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine())).ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Comment: Argument 1: cannot convert string to double line 15

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to break out the calculation into a method, you just create the following method below your main method:

```
    private static double CalculateCircumference(double radius)
    {
        return 2 * radius *  Math.PI;
    }
```

And then call it from within your main method like so:

```
    double circumference = CalculateCircumference(radius);
```

All in all

```
    static void Main()
    {
        Print("What is the radius of your circle: ");
        double radius = ParseInputNumber();
        double circumference = CalculateCircumference(radius);
        Print("The Circumference of your circle is: " + circumference);
        WaitForKeystroke();
    }

    private static void Print(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(message);
    }

    private static double ParseInputNumber()
    {
        return double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    }
    private static void WaitForKeystroke()
    {
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static double CalculateCircumference(double radius)
    {
        return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    }
```